# Stockcheck to update stock table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So my project is coming along well now and I wave created a new form for the user to manually enter stock levels after a stock take.

The coding I have so far is as follows

```
Private Sub StockTake_Click()

'Introduce items and variables
Dim Carling As Integer
Dim Carlsburg As Integer
Dim IPA As Integer
Dim Strongbow As Integer
Dim RevJames As Integer
Dim Becks As Integer
Dim WKDBlue As Integer
Dim WKDRed As Integer
Dim SmirnoffIce As Integer
Dim KoppaburgPear As Integer
Dim KoppaburgSum As Integer
Dim Bulmers As Integer
Dim Vodka As Integer
Dim Gin As Integer
Dim Sherry As Integer
Dim Sambuca As Integer
Dim Rum As Integer
Dim Port As Integer
Dim Whiskey As Integer
Dim Baileys As Integer
Dim Jagermeister As Integer
Dim Martini As Integer
Dim CokeCan As Integer
Dim Coke As Integer
Dim LemonadeCan As Integer
Dim Lemonade As Integer
Dim Squash As Integer
Dim Tonic As Integer
Dim RedBull As Integer
Dim Nuts As Integer
Dim Crisps As Integer
Dim SQLError As String
Dim SQLDelete As String
Dim SQLUpdate As String
Dim SQLBackup As String
Dim PubStock As Integer

'define items. these "Txtname" are text boxes on the form that the user can enter the values into... already this seems like a massive 'code.
Carling = txtCarling
Carlsburg = txtCarlsburg
IPA = txtIPA
Strongbow = txtStrongbow
RevJames = txtRevJames
Becks = txtBecks
WKDBlue = txtWKDBlue
WKDRed = txtWKDRed
SmirnoffIce = txtSmirnoffIce
KoppaburgPear = txtKopPear
KoppaburgSum = txtKopSum
Bulmers = txtBulmers
Vodka = txtVodka
Gin = txtGin
Sherry = txtSherry
Sambuca = txtSambuca
Rum = txtRum
Port = txtPort
Whiskey = txtWhiskey
Baileys = txtBaileys
Jagermeister = txtJagermeister
Martini = txtMartini
CokeCan = txtCokeCan
Coke = txtCokeDra
LemonadeCan = txtLemonadeCan
Lemonade = txtLemonadeDra
Squash = txtSquash
Tonic = txtTonic
RedBull = txtRedBull
Nuts = txtNuts
Crisps = txtCrisps

'introduce SQL coding
SQLDelete = "DELETE * FROM TblStock"

SQLUpdate = "update the tblstock with the values from the form based on the name of the product. tblStock contains StockID*, ProductID and stockLevel which is just the added stock values, not the on hand stock. thus the new value inputed on the form should replace all current values in the table. "

SQLBackup = "export all data in tblStock to update values in an excel table, ie, add to the data allready there, not replace it."

'Start actual coding
If Carling = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Carlsburg = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If IPA = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Strongbow = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If RevJames = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Becks = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If WKDBlue = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If WKDRed = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the  Stock Take and try again" Else
If SmirnoffIce = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If KoppaburgPear = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If KoppaburgSum = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Bulmers = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Vodka = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Gin = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Sherry = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Sambuca = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Rum = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Port = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Whiskey = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Baileys = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Jagermeister = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Martini = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If CokeCan = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Coke = Null Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If LemonadeCan = Null Then MsgBox "Please Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Lemonade = Null Then MsgBox "Please Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Squash = Null Then MsgBox "Please Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Tonic = Null Then MsgBox "Please Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If RedBull = Null Then MsgBox "Please Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Nuts = Null Then MsgBox "Please Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else
If Crisps = Null Then MsgBox "Please Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again" Else PubStock = 1


If PubStock = 1 Then DoCmd.RunSQL SQLBackup
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLDelete
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLUpdate

If PubStock <> 1 Then MsgBox "Plese Fill in all areas of the form to complete the Stock Take and try again"

End Sub
```

kk, apart from the fact I am missing two of the sql queries, can anyone see any other problems with the coding? it seems overly large and I feel like I am seriously missing something important or obvious that would make this more manageable.

Other than the fact it is rather large, and I think I have the massive "If" segment wrong to say the very least, can anyone help me with the sql that might be used for the SQLUpdate? I fear that this is going to be a large chunk as well...  there must be an easier way than this... :(

Can attach database if it can help.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Never never never hard code product names in the program! What would happen if you add a new item??? Keep the products in a 'products' table.

Answer (score 3):

You can make this a lot easier.  Easier to code initially, and easier to maintain later.

Create a table, *tblStockItems*, with 2 fields: item_id (primary key); and item_name.

```
item_id item_name
      1 Baileys
      2 Becks
      3 Bulmers
```

Create another table, *tblScratchInventory*, with 2 numeric fields: item_id; and  quantity.

Create this query and save it as *qryScratchInventory*:

```
SELECT
    inv.item_id,
    items.item_name,
    inv.quantity
FROM
    tblScratchInventory AS inv
    INNER JOIN tblStockItems AS items
    ON inv.item_id = items.item_id
ORDER BY items.item_name;
```

Create a continuous form which uses qryScratchInventory as its record source.  Set the form's Allow Additions and Allow Deletions properties to No.  During form open, you can "freshen" tblScratchInventory to prepare it for recording a new set of inventory values.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSql As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSql = "DELETE FROM tblScratchInventory;"
    db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    strSql = "INSERT INTO tblScratchInventory ( item_id )" & vbCrLf & _
        "SELECT tblStockItems.item_id" & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM tblStockItems;"
    db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    Set db = Nothing
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

You should also include an error handler to deal with any problems which *dbFailOnError* turns up.

Add a command button, *cmdDone*, to the form footer. Use this code as its click event.

```
Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
    Dim lngNumNulls As Long
    Dim strNullItems As String
    Dim strMsg As String

    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    lngNumNulls = DCount("*", "tblScratchInventory", "quantity Is Null")
    Select Case lngNumNulls
    Case 0
        ' do what you need here '
        ' then close the form: '
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.name
    Case Is <= 6 ' list individual items if not too many of them '
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim strSql As String
        strSql = "SELECT item_name" & vbCrLf & _
            "FROM qryScratchInventory" & vbCrLf & _
            "WHERE quantity Is Null" & vbCrLf & _
            "ORDER BY item_name;"
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)
        With rs
            Do While Not .EOF
                strNullItems = strNullItems & vbCrLf & !item_name
                .MoveNext
            Loop
            .Close
        End With
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
        strMsg = "Please input quantities for these items: " & strNullItems
    Case Else
        strMsg = "Please input quantities for all items."
    End Select
    If Len(strMsg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox strMsg
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm uncertain what you want to do with the inventory values after making sure all stock items have non-Null values (Case 0, ' do what you need here ' in cmdDone_Click).  Perhaps you want an UPDATE statement to transfer the quantities to another table (TblStock?).  Or perhaps you can base the form on a query of TblStock, instead of using qryScratchInventory as an intermediate step.